# Date drill up - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

On a published tableau report you can drill down the Date axis to get a more granular view, ie Quarter to months to days.
My question is - there is no drill up to go back ie days to months to quarters. Any one knows how to go up? You only get a plus button and not a minus button.
Thanks

Gemmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is actually a minus button, just checked.

If you have a Date axis by years, and click the + button, it will create a sub axis of quarters, but the year axis will still be there. You can go deeper by clicking the + button on the quarters axis, or go back to just year level by clicking the - button on the year axis (always look for the - button on the top aggregated axis)

Answer (score 0):

For discrete dates Tableau shows both the minus and plus buttons for changing the granularity of aggregation.

For continuous dates Tableau only shows the plus button for drilling down. It is super frustrating. The only way to change the date aggregation if you use the continuous measure is to click on the right side of the pill and select the desired aggregation level form the options listed.

Here is a link to a Tableau forum where people are asking for the drill up feature to be added: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1304

This like discusses continuous and discrete date types in some detail
http://vizpainter.com/dates-in-tableau-make-me-want-to-tear-my-hair-out/

Answer (score 0):

You will find a minus symbol in the published view after you hover over the left side of the aggregated view.
Say you want to view the drill up for quarter, hover over near the quarter on the left as shown in the picture below and you will find the icon.[minus view (check the arrow area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zOzk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible to view (-) after click on (+) sign because the reason is that when you expand the year and view quarter of month year will be there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHwrK.png)

back to minus sign (-) click and collapse the year.